# Pygame not returning mouse position in fullscreen mode

Tags: python, pygame, mouseevent, fullscreen

Trying to create a simple bit of code that registers mouse position on click when in window and also when in fullscreen.

Currently the correct values will be returned when in windowed mode (providing cursor is over the window) however in fullscreen regardless of the mouse position I'm returned the value 800,480 (screen resolution). Here is my code:

```
import pygame

windowwidth = 800
windowheight = 480
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowwidth, windowheight))
pygame.display.flip()

running = 1
while running:
    LEFT = 1
    event1 = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event1:
         if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
              print(event.pos)
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                   pygame.display.set_mode((800,480), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
              if event.key == pygame.K_g:
                   pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480))
              else:
                   break

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

While @Michael O'Dwyer's answer suffices, in addition to his clarification of pre-determining the canvas size of the PyGame window, you could also detect your system's width and height automatically using the `pygame.display.Info()` method for better clarity. Here would be your code with automatically detected width and height:

```
import pygame

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Get system display information
displayInfo = pygame.display.Info()
windowwidth = displayInfo.current_w
windowheight = displayInfo.current_h

# Commented out - No need to reinitialize other Pygame modules
# after pygame.init() is called
# pygame.display.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowwidth, windowheight))
pygame.display.flip()

running = 1
while running:
    LEFT = 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
              print(event.pos)
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                   pygame.display.set_mode((windowwidth, windowheight), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
              if event.key == pygame.K_g:
                   pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480))
              else:
                   break

    pygame.display.flip()
```

[Here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info) is the PyGame documentation for the `pygame.display.Info()` method.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Unfortunately Im still not having much luck with the registering of mouse positions

Comment: @Jkind9 the code is working as intended. In what ways are the registering of the mouse position off?

Comment: Whenever I click on the screen when in fullscreen mode regardless of where I click it only records a position of 800, 480

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that pygame is getting it's mouse-click coordinates in pixels which is tied to the resolution that is passed in `pygame.display.set_mode()`. So because you are setting the resolution to (800, 480) when it goes fullscreen, it isn't going to give you accurate pixel coordinates.

The solution?

Pass in the real monitor resolution when going full screen. In pygame, if you pass in (0, 0) as the resolution, pygame will create a full-screen resolution for you.

So pass in this special screen size and a fullscreen flag and that's it! The code now works!

I hope this answer helped you! If you have any further questions please post a comment below!

```
import pygame

windowwidth = 0
windowheight = 0
pygame.init()
pygame.display.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((windowwidth, windowheight))
pygame.display.flip()

running = 1
while running:
    LEFT = 1
    event1 = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event1:
         if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == LEFT:
              print(event.pos)
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
              if event.key == pygame.K_f:
                   pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
              if event.key == pygame.K_g:
                   pygame.display.set_mode((800, 480))
              else:
                   break    

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Unfortunately even after this correction nothing has changed!

Comment: Could the issue be  caused due to displaying a background image atall?

Comment: If you run the exact code given in the answers does it register the mouse positions correctly? I've just tried it again and I can confirm that it works.

Comment: The code here works, but my full program with the socket does not. Adding in components now to figure out whats wrong

Comment: It seems setting the mouse to invisible is the issue

Comment: I'd recommend trying to debug the program by incrementally adding in features (relating to the window and mouse) starting from the bare-bones code here and ending at your current code. That way you can spot when the code stops working and what is causing the problem!

Comment: Maybe im putting the set mouse to invisible in the wrong place, but that has 100% caused my issue. How strange!

Comment: I have added in the line `pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)` before the line `running = 1` and it is still working fine for me...